# Create columns with the frequency of a code per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to perform a query where I can count the number of distinct codes per Id.

```
   |Id  | Code
   ------------
   | 1  |   C   
   | 1  |   I   
   | 2  |   I   
   | 2  |   C   
   | 2  |   D   
   | 2  |   D   
   | 3  |   C
   | 3  |   I   
   | 3  |   D 
   | 4  |   I   
   | 4  |   C
   | 4  |   C
```

The output should be something like:

```
   |Id  | Count | #Code C | #Code I | #Code D
   -------------------------------------------
   | 1  | 2     |    1    |    1    |   0  
   | 2  | 3     |    1    |    0    |   2  
   | 3  | 3     |    1    |    1    |   1  
   | 4  | 2     |    2    |    1    |   0
```

Can you give me some advise on this?

Comment: Have a look at pivots, there are 100's of examples of these and `COUNT`/`SUM`.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your tip! Will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(case when code = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as code_c,
       sum(case when code = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) as code_i,
       sum(case when code = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as code_d
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Thank you for your answer @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below SQL code in SQL Server.

```sql
DECLARE @table Table(Id tinyint,  Code CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @table 
values
    (1     ,'C'),   
    (1     ,'I'),   
    (2     ,'I'),   
    (2     ,'C'),   
    (2     ,'D'),   
    (2     ,'D'),   
    (3     ,'C'),
    (3     ,'I'),   
    (3     ,'D'), 
    (4     ,'I'),   
    (4     ,'C'),
    (4     ,'C');

SELECT Id, c+d+i as [Count], [c] as [#Code C],[d] as [#Code D],[i] as [#Code I] 
FROM @table
PIVOT
(
Count(code) FOR code IN ([c],[d],[i])
) as pvt
```

```
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Id | Count | #Code C | #Code D | #Code I |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |     2 |       1 |       0 |       1 |
|  2 |     4 |       1 |       2 |       1 |
|  3 |     3 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
|  4 |     3 |       2 |       0 |       1 |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: thank you for your time and answer, but Gordon Linoff's approach is easier for me to understand (beginner). Will look into Pivot tho.

Comment: @mburns, no problem at all. Glad that you found an answer for your problem.